# Biblatex Change field format for a specific entry type

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting

I want to change the field format of `editor` only when the entry type is `incollection`. So that the author name remains bold. The editor name should not be bold.

I've attached an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
%
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,%
citestyle=authoryear,%-comp,%
bibstyle=authortitle,%
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage{newtxtext}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\fontspec[
% SmallCapsFont=Times,
 SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]{Times New Roman}
 %\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont=Times]{Times New Roman}
%
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 
% ===
% ===============
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}% kein Punkt am Ende im LitVZ
% ==========================================================
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}%Kapitaelchen Name
%\renewcommand{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\textsc{#1}}%Kapitaelchen Vorname
% ==========================================================
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{~/\space}% Separation der Autoren
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{~/\space}%
% ==========================================================
%\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{}%\newunitpunct}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}% Bibentry Felder werden mit Komma getrennt
% ==========================================================
\renewbibmacro{in:}{% kein 'in' bei @article
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
% ==========================================================
\renewbibmacro{issue+date}{%
  %\printtext[parens]{% Klammern um Jahr weg
    \printfield{issue}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%}%
  \newunit}
% ===============
% =====
\newbibmacro*{cite:article:journal}{%
       \newunit
       \printfield{journaltitle}
       %\newunit% no comma between journal and year
}
%
\newbibmacro*{cite:article:pages}{%
\newunit%\addcomma
\printfield{pages}}
%
\newbibmacro*{cite:book:shorttitle}{%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
%
\renewbibmacro{postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {%\setunit{%\postnotedelim}%
    \printfield{postnote}}}
% ======================
\makeatletter
%% ===
\renewbibmacro{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
       \ifentrytype{book}% === field
       {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\usebibmacro{cite:book:shorttitle}}% === true
       {}%\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}% === false
        \ifentrytype{article}% === field
        {\usebibmacro{cite:article:journal}\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}
        \usebibmacro{cite:article:pages}%
        }% === true
     {}% === false
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}
    }
    }
\makeatother
% ===
% ===
% ===
% =========== incollection bib driver
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{editor+others}% It shouldn't be bold
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
%  \usebibmacro{editor+others}% OLD
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
% ===
% ===
% ===
% === BIB
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book,
    author      = {Brox, Hans and Walker, Wolf-Dietrich},
    shortauthor = {Brox/Walker},
    title       = {Allgemeiner Teil BGB},
    shorttitle  = {BGB AT},
    year        = {2012},
    edition     = {36},
}

@article{article,
    author      = {Jorg Neuner},
    title       = {Was ist eine Willenserklärung?},
    journal     = {JuS},
    year        = {2007},
    pages       = {881-888},
}

@misc{misc,
    TITLE           = {Beck'scher Online-Kommentar BGB},
    SHORTTITLE      = {},
    EDITOR          = {Bamberger, Heinz Georg and Roth, Herbert and Hau, Wolfgang and Poseck, Roman},
    SHORTAUTHOR     = {BeckOK},
    VOLUME          = {},
    VOLUMETITLE     = {},
    YEAR            = {2018},
    ADDRESS         = {},
    EDITION         = {45},
    %HOWCITED       = {1},
}

@incollection{incoll,
    TITLE           = {Unvernunft als Zurechnungskriterium in den "Retterfällen"},
    AUTHOR          = {Beckemper, Katharina},   
    BOOKTITLE       = {Strafrecht als Scientia Universalis - Festschrift f{\"u}r Claus Roxin zum 80. Geburtstag},
    EDITOR          = {Manfred, Heinrich},
    SHORTTITLE      = {FS Roxin},
    YEAR            = {2011},
    PAGES           = {397--411},
}
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{document}
\fontspec[
 %SmallCapsFont=Times,
 SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]{Times New Roman}
% ===
\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
%
I want to achieve that the editor is not bold when using the \verb|\ifentrytype{incollection}|.\footcite{incoll}\\
\\The author should remain bold.
\end{document}
```

I'm also using this `biblatex.cfg`:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}
%
% ==========================================================
% === Autoren Fett, Nachname, Vorname ====
%
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first-bold}
\DeclareNameFormat{last-first-bold}{\mkbibbold{%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiveni}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}
% ==========================================================
% === Titel nicht kursiv ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\normalfont{#1}}% Zitate: Schriftart der Titel
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\normalfont{#1}}% Titel im LitVZ
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\normalfont{#1}}%
% ==========================================================
% === kein Punkt in Library ===
%
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}% Kein Punkt am Ende des Eintrags im LitVZ
% ==========================================================
% === Hrsg. ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat{authortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}% Authortyp in Klammern
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}% Editortyp in Klammern
% ==========================================================
\DeclareDelimFormat{authortypedelim}{\space}% Kein Komma nach Autor
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\space}% Kein Komma nach Editor
% ==========================================================
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addspace%\labelnamepunct% Kein Punkt zwischen Autoren und Werk
}
% ==========================================================
% === Auflage/Aufl. ===
%
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  edition          = {\ifbibliography{Auflage}{Aufl\adddot}},% 'Auflage' statt 'Aufl.'
}
% ==========================================================
% === Erkennt Satzzeichen & setzt kein Komma ausser bei Abkurzungen ===
%
\DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{\DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*}}
% ==========================================================

\endinput
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of `biblatex` are you running? (You can find out by adding `\listfiles` to the beginning of your `.tex` file, TeX will then write a list of packages and their versions to the `.log` file.)

Comment: @moewe  biblatex 3.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use `editor+others` after `in:` for `@incollection` and friends. Instead I would define a new macro that can be used in that place and uses its own format.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
%
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,%
citestyle=authoryear,%-comp,%
bibstyle=authortitle,%
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given-bold}
\DeclareNameFormat{family-given-bold}{\mkbibbold{%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiveni}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}


\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\normalfont{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\normalfont{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\normalfont{#1}}%

\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat{authortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{authortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  edition          = {\ifbibliography{Auflage}{Aufl\adddot}},
}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{\DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*}}


\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
%\renewcommand{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addnbspace/\space}%
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}%

%\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{}%\newunitpunct}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\renewbibmacro{issue+date}{%
  %\printtext[parens]{%
    \printfield{issue}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%}%
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro*{cite:article:journal}{%
  \newunit
  \printfield{journaltitle}%
  %\newunit%
}

\newbibmacro*{cite:article:pages}{%
  \newunit%\addcomma
  \printfield{pages}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:book:shorttitle}{%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}

\renewbibmacro{postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {%\setunit{%\postnotedelim}%
     \printfield{postnote}}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \ifentrytype{book}%
       {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\usebibmacro{cite:book:shorttitle}}%
       {}%\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
     \ifentrytype{article}%
       {\usebibmacro{cite:article:journal}\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}
        \usebibmacro{cite:article:pages}}
       {}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}
\makeatother


%%%%%%%%%%%% answer starts here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{family-given}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:in:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\printnames[ineditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}
\newbibmacro*{in:editor}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:in:editor}{editorstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{in:editor+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:in:editor}{editor+othersstrg}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:editor+others}%<----- new macro
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
%  \usebibmacro{editor+others}% OLD
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book,
  author      = {Brox, Hans and Walker, Wolf-Dietrich},
  title       = {Allgemeiner Teil BGB},
  shorttitle  = {BGB AT},
  year        = {2012},
  edition     = {36},
}

@article{article,
  author      = {Jorg Neuner},
  title       = {Was ist eine Willenserklärung?},
  journal     = {JuS},
  year        = {2007},
  pages       = {881-888},
}

@misc{misc,
  title       = {Beck'scher Online-Kommentar BGB},
  editor      = {Bamberger, Heinz Georg and Roth, Herbert and Hau, Wolfgang and Poseck, Roman},
  shortauthor = {BeckOK},
  year        = {2018},
  edition     = {45},
  %HOWCITED   = {1},
}

@incollection{incoll,
  title      = {Unvernunft als Zurechnungskriterium in den \enquote{Retterfällen}},
  author     = {Beckemper, Katharina},
  booktitle  = {Strafrecht als Scientia Universalis - Festschrift für Claus Roxin zum 80. Geburtstag},
  editor     = {Manfred, Heinrich},
  shortitle  = {FS Roxin},
  year       = {2011},
  pages      = {397--411},
}
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{document}
\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
%
I want to achieve that the editor is not bold when using the \verb|\ifentrytype{incollection}|.\footcite{incoll}\\
\\The author should remain bold.
\end{document}
```

Note that in the MWE I merged the contents of `biblatex.cfg` into the preamble. At least here I saw no good reason to keep the two separated (and it makes the example self-contained).

[image]